# How to fetch JSON from a php script

Tags: javascript, json, google-maps

I am able to  plot a list of point on a Google map using :

```
(function() {

    window.onload = function() {

        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
          center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.6, -0.88),
          zoom: 12,
          mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        });


        // Creating the JSON data

         var json = [
                {
            "nombre": "NAME1",
            "lat": "41.653",
            "long": "-0.907922",

        },
        {
            "nombre": "NAME2",
            "lat": "41.6693",
            "long": "-0.891317",

        },

        {
            "nombre": "NAME3",
            "lat": "41.6502",
            "long": "-0.875212",
        }
    ];


        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

        for (var i = 0, length = json.length; i < length; i++) {
            var data = json[i],
                latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(data.lat, data.long);

            // Creating a marker and putting it on the map
            //var iconBase = 'https://dea-srl.net/domenico/traking/js/';
            var iconBase = 'https://maps.google.com/mapfiles/kml/shapes/';
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: latLng,
                map: map,
                title: data.nombre,
                icon: iconBase + 'schools_maps.png'
                });

            (function(marker, data) {

                // Attaching a click event to the current marker
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(e) {
                    infoWindow.setContent(data.nombre);
                    infoWindow.open(map, marker);
                });

            })(marker, data);
        }
    }

})();
```

It works well, but I need to read my location from a json string format generated that a like this:

```
{
    "locations": [
        {
            "nombre": "Name1",
            "lat": "41.6504",
            "long": "-0.879137",

        },
        {
            "nombre": "NAME2",
            "lat": "41.6405",
            "long": "-0.893266",

        }    
 ]
}
```

This Json is generated froma php script, thaht is available by a url like: http://myscript.php.

My question is, how can I fetch the JSON from the php script and put it into a JavaScript variable?

Comment: This is JavaScript code, not jQuery. jQuery is a plugin for JavaScript, which is a language.

Answer (score 0):

The objects have the same structure.

Where it says `json.length` and `json[i]`, use `yourvariable.locations.length` and `yourvariable.locations[i]`, respectively.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your variable your own.

```
var json = [];

$.each(yourvariable.locations[0], function(index, value) {

var step = {
   nombre : value.nombre,
   lat : value.lat,
   lon : value.long
}
json.push(step);
```

});

Comment: Maybe I'm just confused but the json you want to have is exactly yourvariable.locations[0].

Answer (score 0):

What you get from myscript.php is just a string. You need to convert that to JavaScript Object

There are many ways you can do this

```
1.<script> var json = <?php echo $JSON; ?></script>
```

OR

```
2. var json = JSON.parse("<?php echo $JSON;?>");
```

OR
You can also consider changing your myscript.php to echo something like this

```
Var json = "$JSON_from_php";
```

and add this to dom,

```
<script src="myscript.php" async="async"></script>
```

OR 
you could fetch it via ajax

```
$.get("myscript.php",function(json) {
    //json will contain the data.
});
```

use `json.locations` in your map generators.

Comment: TX for your complete answer. I try :                           var json =JSON.parse("myurl.php");                                    
and use json.locations.length and json.locations[i] but points do not appear.

Comment: JSON.parse accepts string .. not the file location.. You have to get the file data in some way